# How to delete several mysql database in a loop using mysqli library?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

With using php mysqli library I try to remove a several database in a loop. When I start to debug a query he return only "false".

```
// Remove database and user 
$mysqli->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ".$obj->db_name." ");
```

**Mysql version is 5.5.44**

Also when I try something like DROP database some_name in phpMyadmin I get DROP DATABASE statements are disables

Does anyone know how to fix this or a different way to delete multiple databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a user you can use:

```
$mysqli->query("DELETE user_id FROM table WHERE user_id = 1");
```

Also try this to getting DROP databases:

You will need to update the following file

```
config.default or config.inc.php
```

Generally the phpmyadmin's libraries folder.

```
line 653 (may very depending on version)
$cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] = true;
```

(restart your MySQL once the value is changed to 'true').

Comment: Read this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62443. I think you may have the same problem. Can you please edit you question with the actual error ?

Comment: When I add $cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] = true; in config file the query is executed with success but only in phpMyadmin, $mysqli->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ".$obj->db_name." ") still return false :(

Comment: First echo out the $obj->db_name to see if you get any value and also try using it like this because it is a string $mysqli->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "'.$obj->db_name.'"")

Comment: You are right - everything is ok with quotes. Thanks a lot

Comment: you are welcome. Can you mark it as solved. And have a nice coding day :)

Comment: About editing the phpMyAdmin configuration file, it's not recommended to directly edit `libraries/config.default.php` and instead you should put your changes in `config.inc.php` in the root phpMyAdmin directory.